# Siamese Network For Image Similarity

Tags: python, image, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-recognition

Where can I find details to implement siamese networks to perform image similarity and to retrieve the most similar image from a dataset

It is difficult to get a large number of image data for all the classes, so only a few images, eg 10 images for some classes, are available for most of the classes.
SIFT or ORB seems to perform poorly on some classes.

My project is to differentiate between the license plates based on the states of the UAE. Here I upload few example images.

[image: DUBAI]

[image: DUBAI]

[image: ABU DHABI]

[image: ABU DHABI]

[image: SHARJAH]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is few training data, no matter how annoying it sounds, the best approach is usually to collect more. Deep networks are infamously data hungry and their performance is poor when the data is scarce. This said, there are approaches that might help you:

1. Transfer learning
2. Data augmentation

In transfer learning, you take an already trained deep net (e.g. ResNet50), which was trained for some other task (e.g. ImageNet), fix all its network weights except for the weights in the last few layers and train on your task of interest.

Data augmentation slightly modifies your training data in some predictable way. In your case you can rotate your image by a small angle, apply a perspective transformation, scale the image intensities or slightly change the colors. You apply a different set of these operations with different parameters every time you want to use a particular training image. This way you generate new training examples enlarging your training set.

Comment: how many images would it need per class to have a better classification?

Comment: This can be very task-specific, your best bet is to give it a try;) A field that tries to handle very small numbers of training data is called "one-short learning".